# Class (Business Object) not appearing in Report Data toolbox for RDLC

Tags: rdlc, objectdatasource, business-objects

I have created a local report in a class library (as embedded resource) and I want to use the existing business objects as the data source for the report. When I try to add the business object from the Report Data toolbox I cannot see the class that I want to choose. What I've noticed is that if the business object is a subclass of another class which exists in a another class library then it doesn't appear. Has anybody else seen this? So what I've tried is this:

Scenario 1:

Class Library 1

1. Reports folder > Report1.rdlc
2. BO folder > MyBO and MySuperClass
3. public class MyBO : MySuperClass

When I open up Report1.rdlc and try to create a  New Object Data Source from the Report Data toolbox, MyBO class is visible and I can select it. If I change my solution to this:

Class Library 2
namespace ClassLibrary2 { public class MySuperClass { ... } }

Class Library 1

1. Reports folder > Report1.rdlc
2. BO folder > MyBO
3. public class MyBO : ClassLibrary2.MySuperClass

Now when I try to add the MyBO class it does not appear in the Report Data toolbox. Unfortunately I'm using a product and my Business objects have to be subclasses of the super class that is in the other class library.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue or is this a bug? Oh, I'm using .Net 4 and VS2010. Thanks.

Kind regards

Sidharth

Answer (score 6):

I found the same issue today and tracked it to the fact that when the project is compiled as 64-bit in Debug mode that the Data Source Wizard does not find anything.  If you switch to x86, they magically appear.  I guess the Wizard is 32-bit.

My current work around is to set Debug mode to x86 and Release to x64.  In this way, I can edit datasources as need be.  The final Release doesn't have any problem running.

However, I did not see it dependent on being a sub-class.  Maybe your other libraries have Debug set to x86 and hence the wizard works.

Comment: This is still the case in Visual Studio 2015.